# Google Developer Console Crash Reading for cocos2dx crashes

Tags: android, exception, cocos2d-x

I have some stack traces in my Crash Tab in Developer Console, I was wondering how to read and debug them. The code is in cocos2dx so its really not human readable.

I know the technique with the ndk-stack where it tell you the class and line number etc. but can it be applicable in this scenario since I don't have the obj/local/armeabi folder with me.

`adb logcat | ndk-stack -sym ./obj/local/armeabi`    is the command which I am talking about.

Is there any other solution to solve this problem, so that I can see what crashes users are experiencing.

Thank you.

A stack trace from the application. How can we trace this? And its crashing on just one device. Galaxy Tab 3 10.1 with such logs.

> Build fingerprint:
>   'samsung/santos103gxx/santos103g:4.2.2/JDQ39/P5200XXUANC1:user/release-keys'
>   pid: 11321, tid: 11321, name: ldhelloworld  >>> com.test.helloworld
>   <<< signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000005
>   Stack frame #00  pc 0002b098   Stack frame #01  pc 00000020 
>    Crash dump is completed

Comment: Can you post a stack trace? I'm not sure why the code being in `cocos2dx` makes it not human readable.

Comment: I tend to think it refers to the code style. If this is the v1 or v2 codebase I can relate. ;)

Comment: I have added the stack trace can you please check.